# My code, when using core data, is crashing with 'index beyond bounds' error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

I'm not sure how to solve this problem. This code runs in each cell every time the user scrolls and shows it in a UITableView:

```
self.isFinishedProcessing = NO;

    [self setNeedsDisplay];

    [self.mediaArray removeAllObjects];
    self.mediaArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("setup_cell", NULL);

    NSManagedObjectID *objectID = [self.entry objectID];
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{

        CoreDataStore *customStore = [CoreDataStore createStore];

        Entry *entry = (Entry *)[customStore.context objectWithID:objectID];

        if (self.cellInfo.numberOfMediaItems > 0) {

            int i = 0;

            int numberOfThumbnails = MIN(self.cellInfo.numberOfMediaItems, 3);

            while (i < numberOfThumbnails) {
                Media *media = [entry.media objectAtIndex:i];

                UIImage *image = [media getThumbnail];
                [self.mediaArray addObject:image];

                i++;
            }
        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            self.isFinishedProcessing = YES;
            [self setNeedsDisplay];
        });

    });
```

The core data store takes the Entry, which is a core data class, along with Media, and puts it in it's own context.

I haven't figured out exactly when this code crashes when scrolling, but it happens when scrolling up and down a few times.

EDIT: NSLog before 'object at index' says there is a count of 3. I actually did entry.media.count for that, to be sure.

Here's the error in full:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
```

Edit 2:

Still haven't solved this problem. I've added this on the end:

```
        if (self.mediaArray.count != self.entry.media.count) {
        NSLog(@"INCORRECT BECAUSE.... media array count: %i, entry media count: %i number of media items: %i", self.mediaArray.count, self.entry.media.count, self.cellInfo.numberOfMediaItems);
        }
```

And it often crashes after a cell with something like this:

```
INCORRECT BECAUSE.... media array count: 1, entry media count: 3 number of media items: 3
```

Not sure how the media array count could possibly be wrong, if it's created relying on self.cellInfo.numberOfMediaItems.

Also worth noting that this only happens when done in a separate thread. Never in the main thread does it crash.

Comment: Presumably it's this line where it crashes? `Media *media = [entry.media objectAtIndex:i]`

Comment: How is `numberOfMediaItems` set?

Comment: It's been very difficult to pinpoint, but quite possibly, yes. Is it a problem with it being loaded in from a different thread, perhaps?

Comment: That's set whenever media is added or taken away, somewhere else in the app. It's accurate. It's essentially a faster way of accessing media.count, as it doesn't need to do the calculation while it's scrolling.

Comment: Try setting a breakpoint on Objective-C Exception throws. Then you can examine the array and the index and try to determine why it's not what you're expecting.

Comment: Does the maybe one of the media entries not have a thumbnail? The error im guessing could be bubbling up?

Comment: When is this method running in your code?

Comment: @Rog it's called in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Answer (score 6):

You are violating **Rule #1** of Core Data with multiple threads.

You must not use a MOC in a thread unless it was created in that thread.

You create a queue to run some work for you...

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("setup_cell", NULL);
```

and then in that block, you are using a MOC not created there...

```
Entry *entry = (Entry *)[customStore.context objectWithID:objectID];
```

If you want to do work with a MOC, you *must* follow the rules.  I will summarize **Rule #1** because it has several clauses.

- If you create your MOC with `NSConfinementConcurrencyType`, you can not
  call `performBlock` on that context.  You **must** use it only within
  the thread that created it.
- If you use `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType`, you **must** access the MOC
  from within the main thread, or via `[moc performBlock]`.
- If you use `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType`, you **must** use it only
  via `[moc performBlock]`.

**EDIT**

Your items are out of sync.  You should only count on what the data actually tells you.  Obviously, you are counting on the count from self.cellInfo.numberOfMediaItems but it is not in sync with your actual data.

You must be very careful when updating data from several threads.  Your code has "lost track" of what is actually happening.  Probably because you have not yet saved stuff into the context from which you are pulling data.

Read the docs on Core Data an concurrency.  Make sure you are not changing anything in another thread without notifying all the other contexts.  You should be using parent/child contexts and/or handling DidSave notifications to keep your data in sync.

Comment: This is a good answer but I don't think it is the cause of the problem the OP is having.

Comment: So I need to move that line of MOC into the queue?

Comment: @Rog you may be right... depending on how the MOC is created in [CoreDataStore createStore].  If it is created with ConfinementConcurrencyType, then it should be safe to use it because it is created inside the async block.  if not, then it is not safe to use in there...  kinda why I gave all the details.

Comment: @Andrew Are you absolutely sure that self.cellInfo.numberOfMediaItems and entry.media are in sync?  Specifically, I'd log self.cellInfo.numberOfMediaItems and entry.media to see if the counts are off.  I know you said you've done that... but the exception is saying that the array is empty.

Comment: Looks much better now, too :-)  Thanks.

Comment: Edited above. Still haven't solved this problem. Followed your advice too, that didn't make a difference.

Comment: Nothing is being saved. It's just grabbing data. And the numberOfMediaItems is correct, it matches the actual media count. I've changed the code all over to the media count (which is marginally slower), and it still crashes.

Comment: If i keep the `Entry *entry = (Entry *)[customStore.context objectWithID:objectID];` line of code where it is, it's using the main context in a different thread. If i move it, it's using an object from the new context in the main thread, which is also the wrong thread.

Comment: Sorry, man.  You've lost me.  Maybe take a step back, look at your code again, and see if you can post a complete example.  At this point, understanding your problem requires more than the snippets you have posted.

Comment: Ok, so currently the Entry object is being created in a background thread, referencing the context which is against the rules because it can only be in 1 thread. If I move it to the main thread, by putting it in before it changes threads, now the context has been created in the main thread, so using it in the background thread means it won't work in there now either.

Comment: OK.  You can create the object tin the background thread.  Make sure you save it, and register to process the DidSave notification.  In there, merge the changes from the background context into your main context.  Now you can safely access the object.  Or, once the save has been made, you can use the permanent object ID to refresh the data in the current context.  Either way, you must follow the basic Core Data rules for multiple threads, or you will experience very bad things.